# Passing Table Sorter Function Through DropKick.js

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, jquery-dropkick

Over the last day or so I've been struggling to get two fairly popular jquery scripts to work together, dropkick.js and tablesorter.pager.js. I'm relatively new to JS, but the problem I'm having is not knowing the proper syntax to pass through the dropkick function.

Both scripts are running off the same version of jquery, and the only problem I'm having is that when a selection is made the number of results displayed do not change. For example, if 10 results are displayed in a table and I select 5 as a select option the table should only display 5 results without reloading the page.

Both scripts work great independently, but dropkick.js doesn't do anything with its values without using a change function.

**Here's the form HTML data:**

Table id: "#user-search-results"

```
<div id="pager" class="pager">
<form>
    <img src="images/first.png" class="first"/>
    <img src="images/prev.png" class="prev"/>
    <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
    <img src="images/next.png" class="next"/>
    <img src="images/last.png" class="last"/>
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option value="1">1 per page</option>
        <option value="2">2 per page</option>
                    <option value="100">100 per page</option>

             </select>
</form>
</div>
```

Note: The low values are for testing purposes.

**jquery.tablesorter.pager.js**

```
(function($) {
$.extend({
    tablesorterPager: new function() {

        function updatePageDisplay(c) {
            var s = $(c.cssPageDisplay,c.container).val((c.page+1) + c.seperator + c.totalPages);   
        }

        function setPageSize(table,size) {
            var c = table.config;
            c.size = size;
            c.totalPages = Math.ceil(c.totalRows / c.size);
            c.pagerPositionSet = false;
            moveToPage(table);
            fixPosition(table);
        }

        function fixPosition(table) {
            var c = table.config;
            if(!c.pagerPositionSet && c.positionFixed) {
                var c = table.config, o = $(table);
                if(o.offset) {
                    c.container.css({
                        top: o.offset().top + o.height() + 'px',
                        position: 'absolute'
                    });
                }
                c.pagerPositionSet = true;
            }
        }

        function moveToFirstPage(table) {
            var c = table.config;
            c.page = 0;
            moveToPage(table);
        }

        function moveToLastPage(table) {
            var c = table.config;
            c.page = (c.totalPages-1);
            moveToPage(table);
        }

        function moveToNextPage(table) {
            var c = table.config;
            c.page++;
            if(c.page >= (c.totalPages-1)) {
                c.page = (c.totalPages-1);
            }
            moveToPage(table);
        }

        function moveToPrevPage(table) {
            var c = table.config;
            c.page--;
            if(c.page <= 0) {
                c.page = 0;
            }
            moveToPage(table);
        }


        function moveToPage(table) {
            var c = table.config;
            if(c.page < 0 || c.page > (c.totalPages-1)) {
                c.page = 0;
            }

            renderTable(table,c.rowsCopy);
        }

        function renderTable(table,rows) {

            var c = table.config;
            var l = rows.length;
            var s = (c.page * c.size);
            var e = (s + c.size);
            if(e > rows.length ) {
                e = rows.length;
            }


            var tableBody = $(table.tBodies[0]);

            // clear the table body

            $.tablesorter.clearTableBody(table);

            for(var i = s; i < e; i++) {

                //tableBody.append(rows[i]);

                var o = rows[i];
                var l = o.length;
                for(var j=0; j < l; j++) {

                    tableBody[0].appendChild(o[j]);

                }
            }

            fixPosition(table,tableBody);

            $(table).trigger("applyWidgets");

            if( c.page >= c.totalPages ) {
                moveToLastPage(table);
            }

            updatePageDisplay(c);
        }

        this.appender = function(table,rows) {

            var c = table.config;

            c.rowsCopy = rows;
            c.totalRows = rows.length;
            c.totalPages = Math.ceil(c.totalRows / c.size);

            renderTable(table,rows);
        };

        this.defaults = {
            size: 1,
            offset: 0,
            page: 0,
            totalRows: 0,
            totalPages: 0,
            container: null,
            cssNext: '.next',
            cssPrev: '.prev',
            cssFirst: '.first',
            cssLast: '.last',
            cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
            cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
            seperator: "/",
            positionFixed: false,
            appender: this.appender
        };

        this.construct = function(settings) {

            return this.each(function() {   

                config = $.extend(this.config, $.tablesorterPager.defaults, settings);

                var table = this, pager = config.container;

                $(this).trigger("appendCache");

                config.size = parseInt($(".pagesize",pager).val());

                $(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToFirstPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssNext,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToNextPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssPrev,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToPrevPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssLast,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToLastPage(table);
                    return false;
                });
                $(config.cssPageSize,pager).change(function() {
                    setPageSize(table,parseInt($(this).val()));
                    return false;
                });
            });
        };

    }
});
// extend plugin scope
$.fn.extend({
    tablesorterPager: $.tablesorterPager.construct
});

})(jQuery);
```

**Working table sorter script:**

```
<script defer="defer">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $('#user-search-results')
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: false, widgets: ['zebra']})
    .tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});

} 
); 
</script>
```

**My latest version to include dropkick:**

```
<script defer="defer">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $('#user-search-results')
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: false, widgets: ['zebra']})
    .tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});

    $('.pagesize').dropkick({
    change: function () {
        tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});
    }
    });

} 
); 
</script>
```

I've tried calling different functions from the pager script inside the dropkick change function, and passed in the required variables for the respective function including 'value'.

**For example:**

```
<script defer="defer">
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $('#user-search-results')
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: false, widgets: ['zebra']})
    .tablesorterPager({container: $('#pager')});

    $('.pagesize').dropkick({
    change: function (value) {
        setPageSize('table#user-search-results', value);
    }
    });

} 
); 
</script>
```

I'm very stuck atm and it's holding up my entire project. As I previously mentioned I'm new to jquery, and I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having A LOT of problems trying get dropkick to put the selects into the same place, but here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/332/) of it working.

```
$('table')
    .bind('pagerInitialized', function (e, c) {
        $(".pagesize, .gotoPage").dropkick({
            change: function (value, label) {
                $(this).trigger('change');
            }
        });
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        // {page}, {totalPages}, {startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
        output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})'
    });
```

- Note that in the select names of the bottom pager (`name="pagesize2"`) had to be different from the top names (`name="pagesize"`)

---

Alternatively, I tried other methods like using [pure css](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/330/), with the selects being wrapped with a `<label>`

```
 .tablesorter-pager select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .tablesorter-pager select {
        padding-right:18px
    }
    label {
        position:relative
    }
    label:after {
        content:'<>';
        font:11px"Consolas", monospace;
        color:#aaa;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
        position:absolute;
        right:4px;
        top:2px;
        padding:0 0 2px;
        pointer-events:none;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    }
}
```

---

And using [uniform.js](http://uniformjs.com/), which is my favorite - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/331/):

```
$("select").uniform();

$('table')
    .bind('pagerInitialized', function (e, c) {
        $.uniform.update();
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    })
    .tablesorterPager({
        container: $(".pager"),
        // {page}, {totalPages}, {startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
        output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})'
    });
```